# Integrate Google Calendar Api to Woocommerce fails to generate Access Token

Tags: google-api, woocommerce, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I try to integrate Google Calendar with Woocommerce with Calendar API. I followed tutorials I found it Google, but when I place an order, the calendar doesn't sync.

The log files have this info:

```
05-13-2016 @ 12:12:03 - Failed to retrieve and generate the Access Token
05-13-2016 @ 12:13:40 - Getting Google API Access Token...
05-13-2016 @ 12:13:40 - Generating a new Access Token...
05-13-2016 @ 12:13:41 - Error while generating the Access Token: Array

  [body] => {
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 401
            [message] => Unauthorized
        )
```

However, when I am logged in on the admin, I can see on Woocommerce->Settings->Integration that I am successfully authenticated.

Client ID, Secret Key and Calendar ID have been triple checked.

**EDIT:**

It seems that by reseting the authentication and authorise my email again, it solve the "unauthorized_client".

However, now I have this in the log:

```
05-13-2016 @ 12:58:43 - Getting Google API Access Token...
05-13-2016 @ 12:58:43 - Access Token recovered by transients: a long string
```

Nothing else and the Calendar kept unsync.

Comment: unauthorized_client means that you haven't authenticated before making the call to google calendar API

Comment: Yes. I know that, but as I said, I am successfully authenticated in the Integration tab of Woocommerce.

Comment: If you where successfully authenticated to google and applying that authentication to your request you wouldn't be getting.  unauthorized_client

Comment: About the authentication. When I reset it and authenticated again, it solved. But kept unsync now without an error on the log. I edited my question